# customer_save_before is Not Called on External Script

Tags: customer, magento-1

I have an external script that adds a customer to Magento, and an observer for `customer_save_before` and `adminhtml_customer_save_before`, but it appears that they are not called using an external script:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

Mage::init();

$x = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$x->setData('customer_firstname', 'FNAME');
$x->setData('customer_lastname', 'LNAME');
$x->setData('website_id', '1');
$x->setData('group_id', '1');
$x->setData('email', 'someemail@example.com');
//set password
//...
$x->save();
```

Do I need to dispatch the event manually? This works, however, if the customer is saved via admin.

Here's the event inside the global which works upon saving the customer via admin:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <company_module>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>someMethod</method>
                </company_module>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_before>

        <!-- adminhtml_customer_save_before >
        </adminhtml_customer_save_before -->
    </events>
</global>
```

Answer (score 1):

- `adminhtml_customer_save_before` doesn't exist imho.

Where is `customer_save_before` defined in your config.xml? in `frontend`? `adminhtml`?

If it is in `global` I would expect it to work. If it is something else, it only works, if you load the event config, like this:

```
Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
```

- check cache
- directory structure (especially upper and lowercase)
- name of your class
- name of your file
- name of your method
- check (with die) wether your observer is included
- Make sure your module is loaded (just break the config.xml), then an error is thrown
- ALWAYS work in developer mode (and make sure you know the consequences, like translation "problems")

Comment: Question has been updated with the event tag. Yes, customer_save_before is defined inside the global.

Comment: Added a list of ideas.

Comment: Thank you. However, the same observer is working (tested with die) if the customer is saved via admin. So pretty sure that the model exists. It's just when the customer save is called on an external script, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to add `Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('global');` to your script?

Comment: Added the Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('global');  and here's the output: Fatal error: Call to a member function addObserver() on null in ..app/Mage.php on line 432